# Can't get file to output contents

Tags: python, io

so I'm trying to get my python program to accept a file from the user, and then truncate the file, add content to it, output the file, and finally close. Problem is it won't output. I've opened the file in write+read mode, but the file won't output on `target.read()`. Here is my source code. Problem is on third line from bottom.

```
    from sys import argv

    script, filename = argv

    print "We're going to erase %r." %filename
    print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C."
    print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

    raw_input("?")

    print "Opening the file..."
    target = open(filename, 'w+r')

    print "Truncating the file. Good bye!"
    target.truncate()

    print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

    line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
    line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
    line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

    print "I'm going to write these to a file."

    target.write(line1)
    target.write("\n")
    target.write(line2)
    target.write("\n")
    target.write(line3)
    target.write("\n")

    print "And now we get to read the file."
    print target.read()
    print "And finally, we close it."
    target.close()
```

I'm using Terminal on my Mac, running python 2.7.
Here is my output.

```
    We're going to erase 'test2.txt'.
    If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C.
    If you do want that, hit RETURN.
    ?
    Opening the file...
    Truncating the file. Good bye!
    Now I'm going to ask you for three lines.
    line 1: asd
    line 2: zxcz
    line 3: qwe
    I'm going to write these to a file.
    And now we get to read the file.

    And finally, we close it.
```

Second line from the bottom is where the output is supposed to be. When is use `cat` to output the file, it has the contents it's supposed to. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Before doing `target.read()` you want to `seek` to the start of the file by doing the following:

```
target.seek(0)
```

If you do not seek to the start of the file, the file "cursor" will be at the end of the file and so when you try to read, you will get nothing. This is because when you write, the cursor advances.

[Useful resource](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm)